# Temp table used in two different transactions

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, transactions

I have the following bundle of T-SQL code:

```
begin tran

  select top 100 *
   into #t 
  from tableA

rollback tran

begin tran

  if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t')is not null
    drop table #t

  select top 100 *
   into #t 
  from tableA

rollback tran
```

When I try to execute this code I obtain the following error:

*There is already an object named '#t' in the database.*

It seems that an objectId tied to table varieble *#t* is not found by the check at the start of the second transaction.

What I'm expecting is that #t will be dropped and then recreated. Why the same variable is not dropped and then I get back an error in the second transaction?

Thank you

Comment: This is a compile time issue. you cannot create the same named temp table multiple times in the same batch regardless of whether they are in mutually exclusive code paths or there is an intervening drop http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/153626/3690

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is a difference between a temp table and a table variable! If you handle only little data, try to declare a table variable and populate it with your data.
Furthermore, try putting

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t')is not null
  drop table #t
```

before the first SELECT INTO as well - this might solve the issue...

Comment: Ok, in this example I used a top 100 select and number of data is little, but what about if I remove the _top 100_? Table variables are good for a lot of data?

Comment: Depends on the number of records and eventusally on the number of columns. I used a table variable for something like 100k records but only with 6 columns or something. Anyways, did you try to put the IF...DROP in front of your first SELECT...INTO?

Comment: Sorry for my long time in answer. I tried with a DROP in front of the first SELECT INTO, but it did not work. I think that @Martin is right: it's a compile time issue.